# filter in "find" ignored when output fed to tar

Tags: find, tar, recursive

I have the following directory structure:

```
test/
test/1/
test/foo2bar/
test/3/
```

I want to compress directory "test" excluding everything which is in subdirectories (depth not predefined), which include strings "1" or "2" in them. In bash shell, i want to use *find* and feed its output to *tar*. I first test *find*:

```
find test/ -not -path "*1*" -not -path "*2*"
```

Output:

```
test/
test/3
```

Great. So i combine it with *tar*:

```
find test/ -not -path "*1*" -not -path "*2*" | tar -czvf test.tar.gz --files-from -
```

Output:

```
test/
test/3/
test/1/
test/foo2bar/
test/3/
```

Indeed, both "test/1" and "test/foo2bar" are present in the archive. **Why were these arguments passed to tar, if they were not supposed to be present in find output?**

Comment: they are subdirectories of `test/`, so were archived because `test/` was archived.

Comment: then i don't quite get how tar works.. Does it mean that first "test/" gets archived, including all its contents, then "test/3/", replacing the "test/3/" which was already included in the archive when compressing "test/"?

Comment: @InternazionalIV, They both get stored! You get two copies of the file or directory in the archive. You can check it with `zcat test.tar.gz | strings`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To expand on what @cuonglm said, `tar` by default operates recursively.  If you pass it a directory name, it will archive the *contents* of that directory.

You could modify your `find` command to return only the names of files, not directories...

```
find test/ -type f -not -path "*1*" -not -path "*2*" |
tar -czvf test.tar.gz --files-from -
```

You could instead use the `--no-recursion` flag to `tar`:

```
find test/ -not -path "*1*" -not -path "*2*" | 
tar -czvf test.tar.gz --no-recursion --files-from -
```

Which results in:

```
test/
test/3/
```

The `--no-recursion` flag is specific to GNU tar.  If you're using something else, consult the appropriate man page to see if there is a similar feature available.

Note that your `find` command will exclude *files* that contain `1` or `2` in the path as well as directories.

Comment: One issue with listing only file names to `tar` is that the metadata for the directories (i.e. permissions) will not be saved. Extracting the archive will create them with default permissions.

Comment: That's true, and why I provided the second option as well.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU tar, you can also use the `--exclude` option to exclude files based on names.

```
$ tar --exclude "*1*" --exclude "*2*" -cvf foo.tar  test/
test/
test/3/
```

There's also `-X` or `--exclude-from` which takes a file from which to read the exclusion patterns.

---

Though as `find -not -path "*1*"`, this will also exclude files whose names contain a `1` or `2`. To only skip *directories* whose names match the pattern, use `find -prune` and `tar --no-recursion`:

```
$ touch test/3/blah.1
$ find test/ -type d \( -name "*1*" -o -name "*2*" \) -prune -o -print |
   tar cvf test.tar --files-from - --no-recursion
test/
test/3/
test/3/blah.1
```

(At least GNU tar and FreeBSD tar have `--no-recursion`)

Comment: That would cause it to ignore files like test/manpage.1

Comment: @DavidConrad, like the original `find -not -path`. Good point though.